# MySQL Subtotals and Totals in Select query

Tags: mysql

I need **SUBTOTAL** and **GRAN TOTAL** on MySQL table.

For MySQL guide I need use the **WITH ROLLUP** syntax.

I have tried this SQL query without success:

```
SELECT
    xName,
    xCode,
    sCode,
    FBB88
FROM
    `doTable`
GROUP BY
    xCode,
    FBB88 WITH ROLLUP;
```

Output:

```
+-----------+-------+--------+-------+
| xName     | xCode | sCode  | FBB88 |
+-----------+-------+--------+-------+
| AAAAAAAA  | XX4A  | XX4AU1 |     1 |
| AAAAAAAA  | XX4A  | XX4AU2 |     4 |
| BBBBBBBBB | XX4B  | XX4BU1 |     2 |
| BBBBBBBBB | XX4B  | XX4BU2 |     5 |
+-----------+-------+--------+-------+
4 rows in set
```

Desired Output:

```
+-----------+-------+--------+-------+
| xName     | xCode | sCode  | FBB88 |
+-----------+-------+--------+-------+
| AAAAAAAA  | XX4A  | XX4AU1 |     1 |
| AAAAAAAA  | XX4A  | XX4AU2 |     4 |
| AAAAAAAA  | XX4A  | SUBTOT |     5 |
| BBBBBBBBB | XX4B  | XX4BU1 |     2 |
| BBBBBBBBB | XX4B  | XX4BU2 |     5 |
| BBBBBBBBB | XX4B  | SUBTOT |     7 |
|           |       | GRATOT |    12 |
+-----------+-------+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Group By is not ANSI SQL compliant, and will throw errors in latest version of MySQL as well. Any non-aggregated column/expression in the `Select` clause, must be specified in the `Group By` clauses as well.

Try the following instead:

```
SELECT
    xName,
    xCode,
    sCode,
    SUM(FBB88)
FROM
    `doTable`
GROUP BY
    xCode, 
    xCode, 
    sCode 
  WITH ROLLUP;
```